# Restrict a generic Class parameter to classes that implement Map

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to write a `Map` builder. One of the constructors will allow the client to specify the type of `Map` they wish to build

```
public class MapBuilder<K, V> {

    private Map<K, V> map;

    /**
     * Create a Map builder
     * @param mapType the type of Map to build. This type must support a default constructor
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public MapBuilder(Class<? extends Map<K, V>> mapType) throws Exception {
        map = mapType.newInstance();
    }

    // remaining implementation omitted
}
```

The intent is that it should be possible to construct instances of the builder with:

```
MapBuilder<Integer, String> builder = new MapBuilder<Integer, String>(LinkedHashMap.class);
```

or

```
MapBuilder<Integer, String> builder = new MapBuilder<Integer, String>(HashMap.class);
```

It seems that the type signature of the constructor argument doesn't currently support this, because the line above causes a "Cannot resolve constructor" compilation error.

How can I change my constructor so that it accepts classes that implement `Map` only?

Comment: Why not use a `Supplier` instead? That way, the users can pass `LinkedHashMap::new` and not be bothered with reflection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `Supplier` instead of a `Class`:

```
public MapBuilder(Supplier<? extends Map<K, V>> supplier) {
    map = supplier.get();
}
```

Which then can be called like this:

```
MapBuilder<Integer, Integer> builder = new MapBuilder<>(LinkedHashMap::new);
```

This is also safer, because a `Class<Map>`  could have no default constructor, which would throw an error (which is not very responsive code)

Comment: You can get rid of the wildcard altogether: `public MapBuilder(Supplier<Map<K, V>> supplier)`

Comment: @ernest_k you can't. Without the wildcard it would fail if you provide an instance of for example `class Sup implements Supplier<HashMap<Integer, Integer>>`. It's a very rare case, but it can happen

Comment: Granted. It would still fail even if you use a lambda (`Supplier<HashMap<String, Integer>> supp = HashMap::new; MapBuilder<String, Integer> mb = new MapBuilder<String, Integer>(supp);` - but this is something I'd personally be happy to have no support for (that's an opinion). This is a good answer, btw.

Comment: @ernest_k Thank you :), I agree though that in a small project it would not make a difference (using the wildcard or not) but when writing an API which is used across different projects it is the way to go and makes the lifes of people using your API a lot easier

Answer (score 2):

The following will work:

```
public MapBuilder(Class<? extends Map> mapType) throws Exception {
    map = mapType.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Will produce an unchecked warning though

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `LinkedHashMap.class` is

```
Class<LinkedHashMap>
```

and not something like

```
Class<LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>>
```

These are also inconvertible types (so you can't cast it) and there's no way to get an instance of the latter.

What you can do is change the constructor to

```
public MapBuilder(Class<? extends Map> mapType) throws Exception
```

Generics are erased at run-time so at run-time all `Map`s will behave just like `Map<Object, Object>` anyway. Therefore it doesn't matter that the class you're constructing from is using the raw type.

---

By the way, `Class::newInstance` is deprecated. Use

```
mapType.getConstructor().newInstance()
```